# How to map each div with different width in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a weird problem. I'm mapping options for a submenu inside of a div (container for the submenu). And I set width of the DIV to be '100%'. However, the following submenu divs take the same width, even though they do not need it.

I have provided some screenshot to describe it better. You see the first submenu reaches max-width which is 400. And automatically, the second div has 400px width even though it clearly does not need it.

[image]

[image]

I tried using width='fit-content', or not assigning width ( so that it calculates it itself ). But they do not help at all, the submenu collapses completely and has like 50px width - which is unreadable.

Is there any way to achieve different width for all the submenus?

EDIT (code):

```
      {showNestedOptions && (
        <Box           
          w="100%"
          maxW="400px"
        >
          {map(props.data.nestedOptions, (nestedOption, index: number) => {
            return (
              <Box>
                <Option textAlign="left">
                  <Box h={'100%'} whiteSpace="normal">
                    {label}
                  </Box>
                </Option>
              </Box>
            );
          })}
```

```
<Box> = <div>
<Option> = <option>
```

all the options have the width of the widest element, and I'd like them to each adapt to the biggest element of each submenu

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Unmitigated I did, sorry about that.